# Angular html to pdf issue

Tags: angular, pdf, jspdf

I am converting my angular html template to pdf , but the pdf generated is totally blank.
I have used jspdf and html2canvas for generating pdf.

```
  openPDF() {
    let DATA = document.getElementById('print-paper');
    if (!DATA) {
      return;
    }
    html2canvas(DATA).then((canvas) => {
      let imgWidth = 208;
      let pageHeight = 295;
      let imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
      let heightLeft = imgHeight;

      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      console.log(canvas, 'data url');
      let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
      let position = 0;
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf');
    });
  }
```

The above is the method for generating the pdf. If I put -100 instead of 0 in pdf.addImage I get some content in pdf and for any other values it is blank.

Below is the html template for angular.

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="print-paper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let question of formattedQuestions">
        <app-questions [question]="question"></app-questions>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

// App Question component

```
<div *ngFor="let answer of question.answers" class="form-check">
  <input
    class="form-check-input"
    type="checkbox"
    id="{{ answer._id }}"
    [checked]="answer.marked"
    disabled
  />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ answer._id }}">
    {{ answer.answer }}
  </label>
  <span class="text-green" *ngIf="answer.correct">(correct)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: when will openPdf() method be called ?

Comment: There is a download button below this page, when user clicks on it the method will be called . @GaurangDhorda

Comment: I have cheked it out and its working fine for me

Comment: DOnt know why, but its now working for me. @GaurangDhorda

Comment: latest version of jspdf is giving some weird errors, and documentation is also not upto date for newer version too. so i used jspdf@1.4.1 and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the `innerHTML` property of `DATA` to retrieve the actual HTML string of your content instead of the `HTMLElement` object returned by `getElementById`

I would suggest, however, to use another templating mechanism, to manage your styling properties.